# Scala: value < is not a member of Array[Double]

Tags: scala

I'm trying to replace the value Array of x if is x is less than 0.000001 then x will be equal to 0.000001. Then return log(x).

Here is my scala code:

```
def log(args: Array[Double]){
  var x = Array.fill(20){math.random}

    if(x < 0.000001){ // error: value < is not a member of Array[Double]
      x == 0.000001}
    else{scala.math.log(x)} // error: type mismatch, it found Array[Double], required: double

 }
```

Thanks for your help!
I'm really really new to Scala, no prior experience on coding except R

Comment: `x` is an `Array`. It holds 20 values. You need something that pulls out each of those values, one by one, so that you can compare and modify. (Hint: rhymes with "nap".)

Comment: You probably want to return something from the method as well. What do you need to return from the method?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This will give you a new array with the changed values:

```
val xx = x.map { y => if (y < 0.000001) 0.000001 else scala.math.log(y) }
```

I am going to guess that you also want to return the new array from the method, so:

```
def log(args: Array[Double]): Array[Double] = {
  var x = Array.fill(20){math.random}
  x.map { y => if (y < 0.000001) 0.000001 else scala.math.log(y) }
}
```

Comment: =>  in Scala is used for function types, function literals and import renaming. Here what it does is maps each value of x, i.e. y to the argument of the function used in the RHS

Comment: Thank you very much! Much appreciated!

Answer (score 2):

In addition to radumanolescu's answer, you can also apply map function with case as shown below (it's a good trick to have the sleeve especially for nested ifs or value bindings):

```
x.map {
    case y if y >= 0.000001 => scala.math.log(y)
    case y => y
}
```

Comment: Thanks for your help! Much appreciated !